# What is the master process running on port 465?

Tags: debian, tcp, udp, debian-jessie, ports

I want to close non used ports in my server, after doing a port scan I found service urd running on port 465. Running lsof I see a "master" process running on that port (also 25, 587,etc..). Question is what is that master process? can I disable it?

> lsof -Pnl +M -i4

```
(...)
master     2508        0   12u  IPv4   21914      0t0  TCP *:25 (LISTEN)
master     2508        0   17u  IPv4   21920      0t0  TCP *:587 (LISTEN)
master     2508        0   21u  IPv4   21926      0t0  TCP *:465 (LISTEN)
master     2508        0  120u  IPv4   22026      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:10025 (LISTEN)
master     2508        0  123u  IPv4   22030      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:10027 (LISTEN)
(...)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is `Postfix`.

Postfix is a very popular open source Mail Transfer Agent (MTA) that can be used to route and deliver email on a Linux system.

Port 25: SMTP

Port 465: SMTPS

Port 587: mail submission agents (MSAs)

Comment: then why does it show `master` instead of `postfix` in the process column?

Comment: The `master` daemon is the resident process that runs other Postfix daemons on demand: daemons to send or receive messages via the network, daemons to deliver mail locally, etc. These daemons are created on demand up to a configurable maximum number per service.

Answer (score 1):

The settings for master process is in `/etc/postfix/master.cf`

You can make it listen on `127.0.0.1:smtp` instead of `smtp` which defaults to all interfaces. That will let it process emails coming from `localhost`. Your system might still want to deliver some alert messages to you, so it might make more sense to keep postfix running.